# Program that reads input text file and writes to a specific output file

Tags: java

One thing I need to add is logic to read 8 lines at a time and assign those 8 lines to each variable. What i'm having trouble with is that i'm not getting a run-time error, but nothing is being printed to the output files. I'm assuming there is something wrong with the logic of the while loop that is reading the input file and assigning it to different variables.

Comment: please post your code as well as a sample of the text file

Comment: if you can't take the time to format (correctly indent and comment) your code, why should I take the time to help you? I assume your issue is you are not flushing your buffer. Use the flush method

Comment: Can you indent your code..? Please..?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I test your code and it worked fine with me.
I think the problem in those functions

```
location.getState()
```

You can submit whole code with all classes if this is not the problem.

Comment: shouldn't this be a comment

Comment: sorry, its posted now

Comment: I added the airline class that has the toString method i'm using to print to the output files.

Comment: all classes have been added

Comment: Just replace `location.getState().equals == "WA"` with `location.getState().equals("WA")` on all equatations

Comment: i tried changing the getState()== to getState.equals() and this is what printed into the excel file for WA: "Airline@5c647e05"

Comment: This is because you try to override toString() function but you have an issue with this.
your code: `public String toString(Designator designator, Location location)`
This is not an override, because you do not write the exact signature of the function which is: `public String toString()`@Override
    public String toString()`
You can either override exactly Or you can simply call your toString function exactly from your application in main function like this: `outputStreamWA.println(airline.toString(designator, location))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm no pro in this... But i think the `PrintWriter` is the wrong choice for the output here.
I recommend using `FileWriter`.

According to the documentations [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) is used to print formatted representations of objects to a text-output stream, whereas you're using strings as parameters for the output.
So i believe [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) would be the more appropriate choice.

Comment: I'll give it a try, but how would that change how I write my toString method to each file?

Answer (score 0):

This is the final if statements in main class:

```
if (location.getState().equals("WA")) {
        outputStreamWA.println(airline.toString(designator, location));
    } else if (location.getState().equals("NV")) {
        outputStreamNV.println(airline.toString(designator, location));
    } else if (location.getState().equals("TX")) {
        outputStreamTX.println(airline.toString(designator, location));
    } else if (location.getState().equals("GA")) {
        outputStreamGA.println(airline.toString(designator, location));
    } else if (location.getState().equals("HI")) {
        outputStreamHI.println(airline.toString(designator, location));
    } else if (location.getState().equals("CO")) {
        outputStreamCO.println(airline.toString(designator, location));
    } else if (location.getState().equals("FL")) {
        outputStreamFL.println(airline.toString(designator, location));
    } else if (location.getState().equals("IL")) {
        outputStreamIL.println(airline.toString(designator, location));
    } else {
        outputStreamOther.println(airline.toString(designator, location));
    }
```